# Node.Js/ Express - simple middleware to output first few characters of response

Tags: node.js, express, response, middleware

For logging/debugging I'd like to output the first hundred characters or so of the response right before its sent to browser. Is there something simple I can do with middleware and the response object to do this?

Ideally its something like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Response snippet: '+((res.body || '').substr(0,100)));
    next();
});
```

Except the response doesn't have a body and I cannot quite figure out where the current body to be sent back is passed.

**UPDATE:**

Peter's answer worked, I figure I'd put my middleware code here to save future viewers a click:

```
App.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var end = res.end;
    res.end = function(chunk, encoding){
        res.end = end;
        if (chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
        }
        res.end(chunk, encoding);
    };
    next();
});
```

Comment: Do you have app.use(express.bodyParser()) somewhere in your app.js? It should be before your routes are declared as part of you app.configure.

Comment: Not using bodyParser but added it in. It seems it makes available body for req, but not for res. I want to peak at what I am sending OUT.

Comment: I don;t know if there is support built-in Express for this. I suspect you'd need to look at the response after the res.render() but I don't know if there are any hook for that.

Comment: you can listen on `res.on('data', callback)` but if you're using `express.compress()` then it would be binary. if this is only for development, you can just not enable compression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you need to hook into the response output API, which is not as straightforward in middleware as hooking into the request processing. The best example to look at is [connect's built-in logger middleware](https://github.com/geta6/connect-logger/blob/master/lib/logger.js#L33-L47). It basically monkey-patches the `req.end` method and forwards that data on to its stream, then proceeds to invoke the real `req.end` function. You need to follow this pattern, which should work fine for non-streaming responses.

That pattern may end up only giving you the last chunk of data (for the case of a streamed response). If so, you need to just monkey-patch `res.write` instead of `res.end` and you'll get access to the first chunk. Just un-monkey-patch `res.write` once you've logged the first chunk.