# Get the res.send value in middleware for expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to create some middleware that would log the request body and response body of all routes.  Logging the request is straight forward, however, I can't seem to get the response. `res.on('end')` doesn't emit any data and I'm not seeing anything specifically tied into express that would emit or apply this.  Would anyone have any suggestions how to achieve this?

EDIT:  Based on the links in kook's answer, I've come up with this, which seems to work well.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var send = res.send;
    res.send = function(body){
      console.log(body);
      res.send = send;
      res.send(body);
    };
    next();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to wanna work. I've got mine set up as `app.use(/myroute, myroute); app.use(seeResDotSend)`. I have a `console.log` inside `seeResDotSend`, as the very first line, which fires fine. But then it doesn't seem to ever reach the `console.log` inside the `res.send = function(body) { ... }`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these posts about similar? I think you should be able to follow their logic in creating your own:

[express logging response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215042/express-logging-response-body)

[Node.Js/ Express - simple middleware to output first few characters of response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690335/node-js-express-simple-middleware-to-output-first-few-characters-of-response)

Comment: Yeah, but the chunk value is always `undefined`