# Express.js - Get the res.send value

Tags: node.js, express

My question is exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267463/get-the-res-send-value-in-middleware-for-expressjs) one. The problem is that when I apply the solution to that question, nothing happens - the value of res.send isn't logged. **I use express 4.16.4.**

Here's my code:

```
/* FILE: /app.js: */

...
const postRoute = require('./middleware/postRoute');
const myRoute = require('./routes/myRoute');
...
app.use('/', myRoute);
app.use(postRoute);
...
```

---

```
/* FILE: /routes/myRoute */

...
router.post('/myRoute', [], (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({ status:'success', message:'Test success. Feels good, man.' });
    next();
});
...
```

---

```
/* FILE: /middleware/postRoute */

const postRoute = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('postRoute: ');
    var send = res.send;
    res.send = function(chunk, encoding){
        res.send = send;
        if (chunk) {
            console.log('postRoute chunk: ', chunk); // This statement is never reached
        }
        res.send(chunk, encoding);
    };
    next();
};
module.exports = { postRoute };
```

When I make a `POST` request to `/myRoute` using Postman, it logs the following: `postRoute:`, and that's it. The second `console.log()` is never reached and presumably neither is any other statement in the same `function()` as the `console.log()`.

The question I link to at the start of my question was from 2015, when I assume they used a different version of Express.js, and that's why their solution isn't working for me? In my middleware code example, I used the code from a question that was linked in one of that question's answers, because it's solution didn't work for me. But that solution's obviously also not working, otherwise I wouldn't be here - and it's from 2012! Who even knows what version of Express they used back then!?

**So to reiterate and conclude my question:** How do I use middleware to log the value passed to `res.send()`?

**Follow up question (but let me know if I should rather ask this in a separate question):** Is there a way to call middleware after the route/response from the route instead of globally. So `router.post('/myRoute', [postRoute], (req, res, next) => {...});` instead of `app.use(postRoute)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. I kept my file structure exactly the same, but instead of `res.send()`ing from the route, I attached the object that I would have sent, to the `res` object and then call `next()` at the end of my route. So for instance, `res.send({message:'blah'});` becomes `res.return = {message:'blah'}; next();`. I use `.return` because I don't believe such a property exists on the `res` object by default and I find it descriptive enough for my purposes. Then in my `postRoute` middleware, I can easily access `res.return`, after which I call `return res.send(res.return)`.

Using my example from the question (`app.js` stays exactly as you see it):

```
/* FILE: /routes/myRoute */

...
router.post('/myRoute', [], (req, res, next) => {
    if(theConditionIsMet()) {
        res.return = { message:'The condition was met.' };
    } else {
        res.return = { message:'The condition was not met.' };
    }
    next();
});
....
router.post('/anotherRoute', [], (req, res, next) => {
    // In this route I don't need to intercept the response, so I just do it like normal.
    return res.send({ message:'Feels good, man.' });
});
...
```

---

```
/* FILE: /middleware/postRoute */

const postRoute = function(req, res, next) {
    if(res.hasOwnProperty('return') {
        return res.send(res.return);
    }
};
module.exports = { postRoute };
```

One flaw I can already see is that I'll now have to restructure all my routes to use this method of `res.send()`ing (or at least all of the routes for which I want to intercept the return value). Because of this, and because I imagine someone more knowledgeable than me could probably figure out a better way to do it, I'm not going to accept my own answer.